# Shift row in 2D Vector

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a Vector like below:

```
vector<vector<double>> A;
```

And have values Like this:

```
1,2,3
3,4,5
5,6,7
8,9,6
```

I want to shift row down with step 3 and then become below:

```
3,4,5
5,6,7
8,9,6
1,2,3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) on the outer vector should do the trick:

```
#include <algorithm> // std::rotate
#include <iterator>  // std::next

std::rotate(A.begin(), std::next(A.begin()), A.end());
```

`A.begin()` - returns an iterator pointing at the first element - or `end()` if it's an empty vector.

`std::next(A.begin())` - returns an iterator pointing at the second element in the vector.

`A.end()` - returns an iterator pointing one step beyond the last element in the vector.

The first and last argument (`A.begin()` and `A.end()`) sets the boundaries for `std::rotate` and the middle argument tells it what the new first element should be.

Comment: Thank you so Much
But what do we do if we want to shift column?

Comment: @Alexanov You are welcome! For column shifting, just loop through the outer vector and shift each element (the inner vector) individuallly. `for(auto& inner : A) { std::rotate(inner.begin() ...` etc.

Comment: what do we do if we want to shift column?